# How can I define a custom tcolorbox environment with color as a parameter?

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

I want to use different colored tcolorboxes. Is there an easy way to avoid all that typing for every single box by using `\newcommand` or a macro?

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[
colframe=blue!25,
colback=blue!10,
coltitle=blue!20!black,  
title= More Test]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` package provides a macro called `\newtcolorbox` to define custom environments; see section 2 in the manual (top of p12, in the current version). Under the assumption that you just want to change the colour, not the tints/shades, you could define a new environment that accepts three arguments (the first of which is optional):

1. additional `tcolorbox` options
2. box colour
3. title

See below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

% new tcolorbox environment
% #1: tcolorbox options
% #2: color
% #3: box title
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3][]
{
  colframe = #2!25,
  colback  = #2!10,
  coltitle = #2!20!black,  
  title    = {#3},
  #1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{red}{A red box}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{green}{A green box}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I read a little in the tcolorbox manual but there was way too much stuff to see the \newtcolorbox.

Comment: @daedalus.p1 I know, the length of the `tcolorbox` manual may be daunting, but it attests to the potential of the package. You'll get more familiar with the manual as you use the package more and more. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: You should add `title    = {#3},` (add curly brackets) in order to support titles containing commas.

Comment: @lmaooooo Done.