# What do the numbers mean in custom environments?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, environment-variables

I'm new to the latex stack exchange, and I just want to know what each number means in custom-defined environments. For example, in this code, the programmer defines a custom `tcolorbox` like this:

```
% new tcolorbox environment
% #1: tcolorbox options
% #2: color
% #3: box title
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3][]
{
  colframe = #2!25,
  colback  = #2!10,
  coltitle = #2!20!black,  
  title    = {#3},
  #1,
}
```

Source: [How can I define a custom tcolorbox environment with color as a parameter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172475/how-can-i-define-a-custom-tcolorbox-environment-with-color-as-a-parameter)

Here there are these `#<number>` tags that seem to show up from nowhere, as well as some square braces `[]` that seem unnecessary.

I've searched everywhere on the internet and I still can't understand what it's all about. Could someone please explain these to me as well as how to make my own environments?

Comment: You will note that the author documented what the arguments are used for. You are lucky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code defines a new type of color box, used as an environment, according to the manual of `tcolorbox`.

The environment has three arguments (from the `[3]` part) the first of which is optional with empty default value (from the `[]` part).

In the code, the supplied arguments are denoted in order as `#1`, `#2` and `#3`. Thus if you call

```latex
\begin{mybox}[width=5cm]{red}{A title}
some words
\end{mybox}
```

you get the equivalent of

```latex
\begin{tcolorbox}{
  colframe = red!25,
  colback  = red!10,
  coltitle = red!20!black,  
  title    = {A title},
  width    = 5cm,
}
some text
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: so for different environments, is the first argument always optional?

Comment: @Kookie No, the first argument is optional if you add `[...]` after the number of argument denotation, in your case `[3]`. The dots stand for the default value you want `#1` be substituted with when the optional argument is missing. So with `\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3]{...}` all arguments are mandatory.

Answer (score 4):

In LaTeX, the syntax to define a new command without any arguments is the following.

```
\newcommand{<command>}{<code>}
```

where `<command>` stands for the name of the command to be defined, and `<code>` is whatever the new command is supposed to do. For example, if you write

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}{Hello}
```

you define a new command `\mycommand` which is just going to write "Hello".

To add mandatory arguments, the syntax is

```
\newcommand{<command>}[<number>]{<code>}
```

Then the command will take `<number>` mandatory arguments. For example, if you put `1` in the place of `<number>`, then the new command will expect one argument, which is called in the `<code>` by `#1`. So

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{Hello #1}
```

defines `\mycommand` to take one argument and to output it next to the "Hello". For example, `\mycommand{world}` will output "Hello world".

Finally, if you add another pair of square braces, you can define a default value for the first argument of the command; hence you make it optional. Continuing with the same example,

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][world]{Hello #1}
```

defines `\mycommand` to take one *optional* argument to be specified with square braces if needed, and which default value is `world`. So `\mycommand` outputs "Hello world", but `\mycommand[everybody]` outputs "Hello everybody".

(I was going to edit my answer to add an example with the case of this `mybox` environment, but it would only be a probably poorer version of egreg's answer.)

Answer (score 2):

When you type out

```
\begin{mybox}{red}{A red box}
```

you r saying

--give  me  a frame with color of the frame as red with  25% transparency

--give  me  a frame with color of the background as red with  10% transparency

--give  me  a frame with title A red Box the font has red color  20% mixed with black

Hope it makes some sense

Answer (score 0):

These are input arguments in a macro. Much like the input arguments in [`\newcommand`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros)

Comment: Ok, so, how would you explain the different braces that you can use for new commands? How would one write them?